# Content under sticky-footer doesn't show

Tags: css, position, fixed, sticky-footer

I'm working on a web based mobile app.
I have sticky-footer, and the content beneath is not visible.
Should I add a padding-bottom to the last child of the content so the text will appear above the sticky-footer or is there any other way to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: yes add the padding-bottom equal to the hegiht of your footer

Comment: Provide us your code so we can check it out.